# Solving Special Riccati

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving the common form of the special Riccati

\begin{align}
y' = q(x) + p(x)y + r(x)y^2\tag{R}\label{R}
\end{align}

The first step Ito obtain a general solution to \eqref{R} is to assume a solution of the form

$$y(x) = y_1(x) + z(x)$$
where  $y_1$ is any solution to the equation \eqref{R}. This reduces the Differential Equation into a Bernoulli Equation:

$$z(x)' = p(x)z(x) +r(x)[2y_1(x) z(x) + z(x)^2]$$

However, doesn't this imply that the differential eqution has two linearly independant solutions? Shouldn't a Differential Equation of order one contain only one solution?

Comment: This is not a linear equation, so you cannot expect a family of solutions depending linearly on parameters. In particular, the result you are mentioning (a linear differential equation has a general integral of dimension one) does not hold. See comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/267311/8157). By all means, I cannot understand what makes you think that the second equation has two linearly independent solutions.

Comment: Oh, and one last thing: the name is spelled [Riccati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacopo_Riccati), not Ricatti. Can you edit, please?